# Compute $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}{e^{x^2\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}-e^x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

As the title suggests, I am trying to compute the limit

> $$\mathcal{L}=\lim_{x \to +\infty}{e^{x^2\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}-e^x}$$

and I am stuck. I have defined the function $f(x)=e^{x^2\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}-e^x$ and I have already proven that it is negative on $(0, +\infty)$ as $$e^{x^2\sin{\frac{1}{x}}} < e^{x^2 \frac{1}{x}} = e^x \Rightarrow f(x) < 0$$ as $\sin{x} < x, \ \forall \ x >0$. Also, the graph suggests that the function is decreasing on $[1, +\infty)$ which would mean that the aforementioned limit is $-\infty$, which is in accordance with Wolfram Alpha's results. However, I can't get any further. I have also tried finding the sign of the derivative on that interval, but to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the limit $\lim\limits_{t \to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}$?

Comment: @user376343, yes I know it and its value is $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write it as: $\lim_{x \to \infty}e^{x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})}-e^x=
\lim_{x \to \infty}e^x(e^{x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})-x}-1)$.
Now lets determine the part in brackets.
$\lim_{x \to \infty}x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})-x=
\lim_{x \to \infty}x(xsin(\frac{1}{x})-1)=
\lim_{x \to \infty}x(x(\frac{1}{x}+o(\frac{1}{x^2}))-1)=
\lim_{x \to \infty}x(1+o(\frac{1}{x})-1)=
\lim_{x \to \infty}o(1)=0$
Therefore, we can write:
$\lim_{x \to \infty}e^x\frac{e^{x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})-x}-1}{x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})-x}(x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})-x)$ The fraction part is characteristic limit (equals 1). The rest is $\lim_{x \to \infty}e^x(x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})-x).$ To determine this, we can apply L'Hospitale rule to: $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})-x}{e^{-x}}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^2\sin (1/x) - x = 0$. Therefore,
$$\mathcal{L} = \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^{x^2\sin (1/x)-x}-1}{e^{-x}}$$ is in $\frac{0}{0}$ form. Applying L'Hospital, we obtain,
$$\mathcal{L} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)-1)e^{x^2\sin(1/x)-x}}{-e^{-x}}\\=-\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)-1}{e^{-x}}$$ Since the above is again in $\frac{0}{0}$ form, apply L'Hospital again.

**Edit:** A better way to look at the limit is to note that $$e^{x^2\sin(1/x)-x}=e^{-\mathcal{O}\big(\frac{1}{x^2}\big)}<\frac{1}{2}$$ if $x>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathcal{O}(\ln 2)}}$. Therefore, for large enough $x$, we have,
$$e^{x^2\sin(1/x)}-e^x<-\frac{e^x}{2}.$$ Therefore, for any arbitrary $M>0$, for large enough $x$, we have, $$e^{x^2\sin(1/x)}-e^x<-M.$$ Consequently, $\mathcal{L} = -\infty.$

Comment: Pay attention: $\;e^{x^2\sin(1/x)-x}>\dfrac12\,$ for any $\;x\in\Bbb R\;\land\;x\neq0\,.\;$

Answer (score 1):

For sufficiently small positive $y$ is $\sin(y) < y - y^3/10$, so that for sufficently large positive $x$
$$
 e^{x^2\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}-e^x \le e^{x-\frac{1}{10x}} - e^x
= e^x (e^{-\frac{1}{10x}} - 1) \sim - \frac{e^x}{10 x}
\le - \frac{x^2/2}{10 x} = -\frac{x}{20}
$$
and that converges to $-\infty$ for $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: @Angelo: I wrote “converges” because OP claims that the *limit* is $-\infty$, and that is true in the [extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). Both versions are acceptable, IMO.

Comment: In the extended real line with [the proper topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Order_and_topological_properties) a sequence/function can *converge* to $-\infty$. – I prefer to keep my formulation as it is, we may have to agree to disagree here :)

Comment: Yes, I agree when you say that in the extended real number with the proper topology a function can converge to infinity. I just say another thing, that is, with the usual topology in $\Bbb R$ a divergent function is a function that fails to converge to a real number, for this reason I think it is better to say “diverges to $-\infty$”.

Comment: I think you could complete your answer by writing $$-\dfrac{e^x}{10x}<-\dfrac{x^2/2}{10x}=-\dfrac x{20}$$ which is a simpler way, in fact it is not necessary to write $1$ in the numerator.

Comment: @Angelo: Done :)